# Автоматический запуск скрипта при изменении файла

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Есть файл new_user.txt, он содержит строки в формате:

```
email@mail.ru:dfhs213qoyA
yandex@ya.ru:JDOSCjSQ323rs
```

Есть скрипт, который делает авторизацию пользователя на стороннем ресурсе, написан на phantomjs. Сейчас туда вставляются email-password вручную. Каким образом можно сделать отслеживание изменений в файле new_user.txt и запуск скрипта?

Comment: вам надо стобы скрипт запустился если новый пользователь аторизируется?

Comment: @Horchynskyi нет, мне нужен скрипт, который будет отслеживать изменения файла new_user.txt, т.е. при каждом изменении файла запускается скрипт. Примерно так же работает gulp, который наблюдает за изменениями файлов и при изменении запускает различные task'и. Нужно похожее, только запускать нужно не таск в галпе, а скрипт, написанный на phantomjs